# How to add a libreoffice launcher for writer?

Tags: applications, dock, launchpad, libreoffice

I have libreoffice 4.3.4.1 on OS X 10.10, it only has one libreoffice launcher in spotlight/launchpad. Is it possible to add launchers for subprograms like writer, calc, impress, draw... ?

Answer (score 2):

As of version 6, in the OsX version of LibreOffice there are NOT separate applications to be run.

It is possible is to create a "launcher" for each LibreOffice components, for example with Applescript, and then to add the resulting app to the Dock or in the Applications Folder -to be indexed by spotlight.

The single line Applescript:

`do shell script "/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --writer &> /dev/null &"`

launches Writer (to launch the other components you use their names instead of writer, that is --calc, --impress, --draw, --base, or --math)

Save the Applescript as an app, and even change its icon (you can google for Libre Office icons or you can search for them http://www.iconarchive.com) and the "illusion" is complete

Comment: Used Gio Valerio's answer, however Applescript threw an error dues to a missing final quotation marks. (") Added those and no problem! do shell script "/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --writer &> /dev/null &"

Answer (score -1):

If you go to Applications, find LibreOffice and right-click Show Contents, does LibreOffice contain separate applications for Calc, Writer, etc? If so, the easiest thing to do would be to drag & drop those on your dock. You could also make aliases and/or symlinks of them.

Comment: Found a bug here: https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50278